# bash shell to add a new line in a file after a pattern match found

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file "**.gitignore**" contains various source file name as

```
src/abc
src/line
src/another
```

I like to add another line "**src/line.cpp**" after a match found "**src/line**"
result would look like as

```
src/abc
src/line
src/line.cpp
src/another
```

I am using sed as

```
set -- "$File"   // $File contains src/line
IFS="/"; declare -a Array=($*)
echo "${Array[0]}"   // This prints src
echo "${Array[1]}"   // This prints line

sed -i '/$Array[0]\/$Array[1]/a $Array[0]\/$Array[1].cpp'  $File
```

The sed command is not working.
I have a feeling that slashes are not properly handled. If I hard code as

```
sed -i '/src\/line/a src\/line.cpp' $File
```

then it works.
Any solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @fedorqui: This is not a duplicate of that; the OP's working line matches your suggested duplicate. Rather, the OP's problem is the use single quotes `'` rather than double `"`.

Answer (score 2):

You properly use double-quotes in `echo "${Array[1]}"`, and the braces `{}` needed for the array index. But you neglect to do so in your `sed` line. So try:

```
sed -i "/${Array[0]}\/${Array[1]} *$/a ${Array[0]}\/${Array[1]}.cpp" .gitignore
```

I've added an extra `$` here for the end of the line, so:

- Repeating the command leaves the file unchanged
- Reduces risk of inadvertent matches

The space-star-dollar `*$` handles the case where a line has blank spaces at the end. You may also want to add a `^` to match the start of line.

Also, your `sed` command operates on `$File`; I think you want `.gitignore`.

But rather than fiddle around with `IFS` and arrays, it might be cleaner to use bash's parameter substitution. Replace `${Array[0]}` and `${Array[1]}` with:

```
  ${File%/*}
  ${File#*/}
```

Finally, you don't even need to do that, if you replace the sed slash `/` with for example `@` (but underscore `_` would be bad, as it is commonly used in filenames).

So the penultimate command line is:

```
sed -i "\@$File@a $File.cpp" .gitignore
```

or, to handle blanks at the end of a line and to avoid spurious matches:

```
sed -i "\@$File *\$@a $File.cpp" .gitignore
```

Note only the first `@` is escaped.

Comment: Thank you!! These are working!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed, you can do it like:

```
sed -i.BAK 's_src/line_\0\n\0.txt_'
```

As it allows to use other separators than slashes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, It works but not when i use variables. sed -i.BAK 's_$Array[0]/$Array[1]_\0\n\0.cpp_' .gitignore

Comment: For that you must use `"` as quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way:

```
s='src/line'; r='src/line.cpp'; sed "s~$s~&\n$r~" file
src/abc
src/line
src/line.cpp
src/another
```